# Laravel waits for a long running request to finish before processing a different request

Tags: laravel, concurrency, laravel-10

My setup is Laravel v10.1.5 (PHP v8.2.4) running on Sail.

I have 2 routes where one is taking longer to respond than the other. The `/shortProcess` returns a response in less than 1 second and the `/longProcess` takes approx 10 seconds.

Routes:

```
Route::get('/longProcess', function () {
    sleep(10);
    return response('content');
});
Route::get('/shortProcess', function () {
    sleep(1);
    return response('content');
});
```

When I send a get request to `/longProcess` and `/shortProcess` together but in that order, the response from `/shortProcess` waits for 11 seconds instead of 1 second.

However, if I send a request to just the `/shortProcess`, it responds in the expected 1 second.

I've even tried using different browsers and users to check if there's some throttling that happens which I'm unaware of. But it's the same results.

Any ideas why Laravel is waiting for the first request to finish before  processing the second process?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Laravel. Check your server setting to allow multiple requests.

Comment: Thanks @AbdullaNilam , it looks like that's the case. Your suggestion make me look into that specifically and I found that Laravel sail uses php artisan serve under the hood instead of a real webserver, so it can only handle 1 request at a time.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/can-laravel-sail-only-handle-one-request-at-a-time